# Facebook Pixel integration on Vue 2.6 with env & custom index templates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, facebook-pixel

FB Pixel is generally blocked when you add meta tag or script dynamically.
And if you have different pixel accounts for your staging and production environments you need to add meta tag & script dynamically getting id & content from env files.
The result is

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

How to achieve run FB pixel successfully?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, a solution is you need to use different index.html templates for different environments.
In default, vue cli using `public/index.html` file to build app. But we can change it using `vue.config.js` as below.

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: "en",
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      localeDir: "locales",
      enableInSFC: false
    }
  },
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "src/main.js",
      template: process.env.VUE_APP_INDEX_TEMPLATE,
      filename: "index.html"
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"]
};
```

as you can see on template, we are using env variables.

and we need to add this variables to all env files, in my case I am using

```
.env.staging 
.env.development 
.env.production
```

and the keys in order

```
VUE_APP_INDEX_TEMPLATE=public/index_staging.html
VUE_APP_INDEX_TEMPLATE=public/index_development.html
VUE_APP_INDEX_TEMPLATE=public/index.html
```

And we need to add FB Pixel meta tag & script files to the templates according to its own pixel account credentials inside the head tags statically.

```
  <head>
    ...
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <meta
      name="facebook-domain-verification"
      content="FB_DOMAIN_VERIFICATION_CODE_HERE_STATICALLY"
    />
    <script>
      !(function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return;
        n = f.fbq = function() {
          n.callMethod
            ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments)
            : n.queue.push(arguments);
        };
        if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n;
        n.loaded = !0;
        n.version = "2.0";
        n.queue = [];
        t = b.createElement(e);
        t.async = !0;
        t.src = v;
        s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
      })(
        window,
        document,
        "script",
        "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"
      );
      fbq("init", "FB_PIXEL_ID_HERE_STATICALLY");
      fbq("track", "PageView");
    </script>
    <noscript
      ><img
        height="1"
        width="1"
        style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID_HERE_STATICALLY&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
  </head>
```